# Issues with QtMQTT install on Mac (Qt 6.6.2)

Tags: macos, qt, mqtt, qt-creator

I have been following this [guide](https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-create-an-mqtt-application-in-qt6) to install QtMQTT on Mac M1 chip with Qt 6.6.2.

In the guide I was able to compile the qtmqtt project in Qt Creator and copy most of the necessary files and folders from the build folder into the newly created QtMqtt directory within my `Qt/6.6.2/macos/include/` directory. However, for the installation guide step

> 3. Copy the two .pri files from build-qtmqtt-Desktop_arm_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit-Release/mkspecs/modules to Qt/6.6.2/macos/mkspecs/modules.

I only see one .pri file, so I copied that over and then tried to run the SimpleClient example project and the build failed. When I recloned the qtmqtt repo and restarted the steps, the qtmqtt project does not even compile anymore in Qt. It gives this error:

[image: Qt error message]

Any help is appreciated!